# Удаление метки с апи яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Использую апи яндекс карт. Для того чтобы поставить метку на карту я отлавливаю событие myMap.events.add('click', function (e) . Как удалить установленную ранее метку по щелчку на ней? То событие которое я указал при повторном клике по метке не срабатывает.

Comment: Добавьте код, где вы пытаетесь это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы слушаете событие клика по карте, когда метка установлена - она перехватывает клик и событие не доходит до уровня карты. Вам нужно слушать событие клика по самой метке и удалять её.

Например, так:

```
  myMap.geoObjects.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var object = e.get('target');
    myMap.geoObjects.remove(object)
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/ysrooLco/